# Safe handle has been closed at Interop.mincore.LsaLookupSids

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-identity

Windows Identity with ASP.net Core 1.1 self-hosted app with `WebListener`

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseWebListener(options =>
                {
                    options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
                    options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                })
```

Some times i'm getting error

> An unhandled exception has occurred: Safe handle has been closed

at methods like `'User.IsInRole(group)'` or `'User.Identity.Name'` and app crashed at this dumb method

```
string userName;
try
{
    userName = User.Identity.Name;
}
catch
{
    userName = "undefined";
}
return userName;
```

The stack trace looks like that:

```
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke Error: An unhandled exception has occurred: Safe handle has been closed Safe handle has been closed    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
       at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
       at Interop.mincore.LsaLookupSids(SafeLsaPolicyHandle handle, Int32 count, IntPtr[] sids, SafeLsaMemoryHandle& referencedDomains, SafeLsaMemoryHandle& names)
       at System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.TranslateToNTAccounts(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceSids, Boolean& someFailed)
       at System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceSids, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)
       at System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(Type targetType)
       at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.<GetName>b__42_0()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedInternal(SafeAccessTokenHandle token, Action action)
       at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.GetUserNameForLogging(ClaimsPrincipal user)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.<AuthorizeAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter.<OnAuthorizationAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext() AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start => <Invoke>d__4.MoveNext => ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invokee
```

Can't reproduce it on debug, but at production get crashed once a week.

Any suggestions?